# Trouble with the inductive proof $1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2} < 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ for all n > 1

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm doing a review/relearning of induction, and having some trouble with the family of problems that have to do with inequalities. Right now I'm struggling with this proof:

$$1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2} < 2 - \frac{1}{n}$$ for all n > 1.

I evaluated P(2) as my base case, and got the truthful statement $\frac{5}{4} < \frac{3}{2}$, which holds.

My inductive hypothesis, therefore, is $1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 - \frac{1}{k}$.

This is where I get lost; if this were an equation with an equality, I would proceed with the inductive step $1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} = 2 - \frac{1}{k+1}$, and then make the substitution based on my inductive hypothesis to get the following: $2 - \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} = 2 - \frac{1}{k+1}$.

I'm still unclear as to how the substitution and subsequent manipulation change when you change the equality to an inequality.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261242/42969